# How to retrieve data by View name with JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, jsom, office-365-developer

Iam trying to retrieve data with SharePoint javascript JSOM, below is my code and iam getting an error "Unexpected response data from server."

```
var getActionPlan = function () {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext($rootScope._spHostUrl);
        var web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("ActionPlan");
        var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("View1");
        var viewFields = view.get_viewFields();
        context.load(viewFields);
        context.executeQueryAsync(printFieldNames,onError);


        function printFieldNames() {
            var e = viewFields.getEnumerator();
            while (e.moveNext()) {
                var fieldName = e.get_current();
                console.log(fieldName);
            }
        }

        function onError(sender,args)
        {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the value of `$rootScope._spHostUrl`? Just put `console.log($rootScope._spHostUrl)` at the beginning of `getActionPlan `

Comment: $rootScope._spHostUrl is =  _spHostUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl.substring(0, _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl.lastIndexOf("/")) + '/_api/web/lists';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SP.ClientContext` constructor accepts full or server-relative url as parameter. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245896.aspx).
In your case you need to use
`$rootScope._spHostUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;`
or
`$rootScope._spHostUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;`

or use web server or absolute urls (depending on your needs):
`$rootScope._spHostUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl`

Comment: $rootScope._spHostUrl is returning : /sites/devsite/h16/_api/web/lists

Comment: This is your issue - url should be `/sites/devsite/h16` or `http://[your sp farm url]/sites/devsite/h16`

Comment: Hi Kai, you are correct, my URL was not in correct format. Now its working fine...thanks for helping.-...

Answer (score 0):

You need to load all fields and viewfields and then compare. see below

```
function displayListFields(listname) {
    var list = lists.getByTitle(listname);
    fields = list.get_fields();
    var view = list.get_defaultView();

    viewfields = view.get_viewFields();
    context.load(fields);
    context.load(viewfields);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetFieldsSuccess, onGetFieldsFail);
}
function onGetFieldsSuccess(sender, args) {
    var viewfieldnames = collectionToArray(viewfields);

    var fieldEnumerator = fields.getEnumerator();

    while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var field = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        if (!field.get_hidden()) {
            var fieldName = field.get_internalName();
            var found = $.inArray(fieldName, viewfieldnames) > -1;
            if (found) {
               //Here you will get view fields

            }
        }        

    }

}

function onGetFieldsFail(sender, args) {
    //List could not be  loaded- display error.
    alert('Failed to get field Error :' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: Just tried your code, getting same error message: Unexpected response data from server.

Comment: try to debug and check where exactly you are getting error